# ds register is invalid in new inline assembly

Tags: rust

I'm trying to port inline assembly code from llvm_asm syntax to the new asm inline syntax, but getting this error:

```
error: invalid register `ds`: unknown register
```

Old llvm_asm! code:

```
llvm_asm! ("
            mov ax, 0x18
            mov ds, ax"
            :
            :
            : "rax", "ds"
            : "intel", "volatile");
```

New asm! code:

```
    asm! (
            "mov ax, 0x18",
            "mov ds, ax",
            lateout ("ax") _,
            lateout ("ds") _,
        );
```

How can i use the ds register in new inline assembly syntax?

Comment: `ds` is not a general purpose register, I don't think it makes sense using it in any `in`, `out` or `lateout`. If the old LLVM `asm` allowed it I'd say it was a bug.

Comment: @rodrigo: In the second table under [Register names](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/library-features/asm.html#register-names), The Rust Unstable Book lists registers that "cannot be used for input or output operands" but `ds` is not included amongst them.  Perhaps the table is incomplete?

Comment: Taking a look at https://docs.rs/x86_64/0.14.3/src/x86_64/instructions/segmentation.rs.html#56-62, it looks like using the segment registers directly is fine, albeit unsafe, obviously.
This matches @rodrigo's claim, where segmentation registers are not general purpose registers and thus not touched or directly used by Rust in any way.

Comment: The segment registers is a part of x86 architecture, therefore anything can use it, and it make sense to notice rust that my code modify them.